# Uploading file using formdata showing error: Uncaught ReferenceError: fileInputElement is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data

I am trying to create a fileupload script using `FormData` but I am getting an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: fileInputElement is not defined`

This is my code at the moment:

```
$("body").on("click","#addemployeebtn",function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    var formdata = new FormData();

    var file1 = formdata.append("copy_driverslicense", fileInputElement.files[0]);

    var $form = $("#employeeformadd");

    var $serialized = $form.serialize();

    var url = 'includes/addemployee.php';

    var posting = $.post(url, {
      serialized: $serialized,
      file1: $file
    });
    // Post to addemployee.php and get result message in .addemployee
    posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".addedemployee" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
    });
});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<form id="employeeformadd" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="copy_driverslicense" type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using this site to try and learn how to do this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Look at your code and tell us were you declared `fileInputElement` variable. You are using a variable that has not been declared

Answer (score 1):

I will not take in consideration any other errors in the code. Just what caused the error "UncaughtReference". refering to the code snippet given above, the variable 'fileInputElement' is not defined any where that's what leads to the error because it's null. And no exception has been caught.

You should consider to access the InputElement using the ID "copy_driverslicence" as stated below:

```html
$("body").on("click","#addemployeebtn",function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    var formdata = new FormData();
//declare first the element;
 

   var fileInputElement=document.getElementById("copy_driverslicence");
    var file1 = formdata.append("copy_driverslicense",fileInputElement.files[0]);

    var $form = $("#employeeformadd");

    var $serialized = $form.serialize();

    var url = 'includes/addemployee.php';

    var posting = $.post(url, {
      serialized: $serialized,
      file1: $file
    });
    // Post to addemployee.php and get result message in .addemployee
    posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".addedemployee" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
    });
});
```

Comment: I get an error with above code: `cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry when declaring the id I used c instead of s copy_driverslicense. Try and let us know if it works

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="" class="form-control" name="images" />
```

JavaScript

```
var formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('file', $('#uploadImage')[0].files[0]);
                        //formData.append('category_name', category_name);
                        //formData.append('Language_ID', Language_ID);

                        $.ajax({
                         url:$('body').attr('url') + 'admin/media/add_image_category_data',
                         type:"post",
                         data: formData, //this is formData
                         processData:false,
                         contentType:false,
                         cache:false,
                         async:false,
                          success: function(data){
```